# How can we have cucumber recognise a ":" symbol after a scenario outline parameter?

Tags: cucumber-jvm

When using CucumberJVM to write feature files, when passing in the variables from the scenario outline examples table, I am unable to get the steps to recognise a variable followed by ":".

Step definition:

```
 @Given("^the following (.*) (.*): (.*)$")
```

**Successfully detects this:**

```
Given the following standard user: <username>
```

**Does not detect this:**

```
Given the following standard <account-type>: <username>
```

I want the best of both worlds, but when passing a variable from this example table for  the step is not recognised by cucumber.

`Examples:
      | username      | account-type |
      | Jason         | user         |
      | Martin        | manager      |`

How can I have the ":" symbol, detected and working within the feature file for both of these scenarios?  is an ENUM and cucumber seems like its failing to convert it in this situation

Comment: Try using (.*?) instead of (.*). If my understanding is correct, that should stop matching at the `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, modify the pattern in the stepdefinition class.

```
@Given("^the following standard (.*?): (.*?)$")
public void the_following_standard_user( AccountType usertype,String user) {
    System.out.println(user);
    System.out.println(usertype);
}
```

`AccountType` is the enumeration.

```
public enum AccountType {

    USER("user"), MANAGER("manager");

    private final String type;
    private AccountType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```